# Matlab circshift - does Matlab round up or down?

Tags: matlab

When I do

```
circshift(image(k,:), [0 Naz/2-5]);
```

When Naz/2-5 is not a round number, eg 74.5

What does Matlab do with it?

I know it's not correct to supply the function with a non-integer, but I am encountering it, and am curious to know what Matlab does.

Does it shift 74 or 75?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried it with Matlab 2014b. An error is thrown in the case the operation does not return an integer. `Invalid shift type: must be a real finite integer vector.`

Comment: @Nemesis Hmm... R2011a allows it .. zzz

Comment: I think you need to add `round` or `floor` or `ceil` yourself to round Naz/2-5 into an Int

Comment: @Nemesis Hmm... R2011a allows it when it is within a m script. I tried issuing the command in the command screen and it has the same error Nemesis. Prob it was also disallowed in .m scripts in later version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply test it manually?

```
A = circshift( 1:100, [0 74] );
B = circshift( 1:100, [0 75] );
C = circshift( 1:100, [0 74.5] );

if( isequal( A, C ) )
    display('A and C are equal -> MATLAB rounds down');
elseif( isequal( A, B ) )
    display('B and C are equal -> MATLAB rounds up');
else
    error('Unexpected behaviour');
end
```

I also cannot test it because I am using R2015b:

`Error using circshift
Invalid shift type: must be a real finite integer vector.`

Hint: use a "ramp" function (ascending sequence from 1 to n) to quickly check your results.

Comment: "simply test it" gets you my +1